# How to pull down refresh (EGORefreshTableHeaderView) in each UIScrollView's page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UIScrollView contains three UIWebView pages.

webPage1, webPage2, webPage3

Now I want to pull down refresh with EGORefreshTableHeaderView for each webPage. Says:

When scroll to webPage1, Pull down webPage1, then refresh webPage1, scroll to webPage2 pull down webPage2 refresh webPage2, scroll to webPage3 pull down webPage3 refresh webPage3

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That library only works for `UITableView`s, not `UIWebViews`.  I'd strongly suggest a different mechanism for reloading the pages.